# Did Satoshi Nakamoto Really Publish A Second Paper In December, 2015?

Tags: satoshi-nakamoto

http://bitcoinnewschannel.com/2015/12/27/page-2-of-the-hash-tube-signature-scheme-credited-to-satoshi-nakamoto/

The guys working at this site claimed that Satoshi Nakamoto sent them a paper titled (hash tube signatures) which you can read via the link.

The problem is those guys that work on that site have been around the bitcoin community since 2009-2010 and some thought they invented bitcoin, so did they make this up? or is it really Satoshi?

Comment: Hard to know for certain, this is fairly subjective.

Comment: It is actually quite easy to know, Satoshi has private keys (bitcoin addresses and php) that are verifiable by others in the community. If they claim to be Satoshi, ask for mathematically verifiable proof.